# How to handle really large objects returned from the joblib.Parallel()?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, generator, joblib

I have the following code, where I try to parallelize:

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

lst = [[0.0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
arr = np.array(lst)
w, v = np.linalg.eigh(arr)

def proj_func(i):
    return np.dot(v[:,i].reshape(-1, 1), v[:,i].reshape(1, -1))

proj = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(proj_func)(i) for i in range(len(w)))
```

`proj` returns a really large list and it's causing memory issues.

Is there a way I could work around this?

I had thought about returning a generator rather than a list, but I don't know how to do this. Any other ways would be welcomed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Is there a way I could work around **this**?"*

That heck depends on what such ***`this`*** stands for.

> Pre-conditions, set for a fair use of the `np.linalg.eigh()`-method, were accidentally not met in the MCVE code snippet posted above, yet these remain outside of the scope of this post. If any complex inputs and results will get processed accordingly, some of the here-referred `N`-scaled RAM-allocations will, for obvious reasons, actually get `2*N`-sized or `4*N*N`-sized or `8*N*N*N`-sized factors in the below depicted scaling of the RAM-footprint requirements, yet **the core-message ought be clear and sound** from the plain `N`-factored sizing dependencies used below :

---

### Is The MEMORY Sizing The Bottleneck ?
<sub>Space for static-sized data :</sub>

Given your MCVE, as was posted above, the MEMORY-sizing depends on **`N = arr.size`**
and your system either has at least :
- **`N * 3 * 8 [B]`** RAM for holding `lst, arr, w`
- **`N * N * 8 [B]`** RAM for holding `v`

Put altogether, there will have to be way more than **`<_nCPUs_> * 8 * N * ( 3 + N ) [B]`** RAM-space, just to introduce `n_jobs == -1` full-copies of the python interpreter process ( definitely that for MacOS / WinOS and most probably also for linux, as fork-method was documented in 2019/2020 to yield unstable/unsafe results ) **before** the code tried to do even **the first call to `proj_func( i )`**

If that is not the capacity of your system, you may straight stop reading.

---

### Next ?
  <sub>Space for dynamic data :</sub>

Any call of the next **`N`**-calls to `proj_func( i )`, each one adds additional RAM-allocation of - **`N * N * 8 [B]`** RAM-space for holding the `np.dot()`-results

Altogether more than **`k * N * N * N * 8 [B]`** RAM for holding `np.dot()`-results, where **`k >> 2`**, as each of these **`N`**-results has to get **`SER`**-packed ( again allocating some RAM-space for doing that ), next each such `SER`-ed-payload has to get transmitted from a remote-**`joblib.Parallel()(delayed()(...))`**-*executor* forward to the main-process ( here again allocating some RAM-space for the `SER`-ed payload ) next this RAM-stored intermediate binary-payload has to get **`DES`**-erialised ( so again allocating some additional RAM-space for storing the `DES`-ed data of the original size **`N * N * 8 [B]`** ) so as to get this SER/DES-pipelined product finally **`N`**-times appended to the inital `proj == []` as the above specified syntax of using the
`joblib.Parallel(…)( delayed( proj_func )( i ) for i in range( len( w ) ) )`-clause insists and imperatively enforces.

```
<_nCPUs_> * 8 * N * ( 3 + N ) //     static storage: data + all python process-replicas
+
<_nCPUs_> * 8 * N * N * k     //    dynamic storage: SER/DES on joblib.Parallel()(delayed…)
+
            8 * N * N * N     // collective storage: proj-collected N-( np.dot() )-results
~
=           8 * N * ( N * N + <_nCPUs_> * ( 3 + N * ( k + 1 ) ) )
```

---

### RESUMÉ :

This soon scales ( even when we assumed no other python-process `import`-s and static data ) well above an "ordinary" host computing device's RAM-footprint for any **`N`** `== arr.size >= 1E3` :

```
>>> nCPUs =  4; k = 2.1; [ ( 8 * N * ( N * N + nCPUs * (3+N*(k+1)))/1E9 ) for N in ( 1E3, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6 ) ]
[8.099296, 8009.92096, 8000992.0096, 8000099200.096]
>>> nCPUs =  8; k = 2.1; [ ( 8 * N * ( N * N + nCPUs * (3+N*(k+1)))/1E9 ) for N in ( 1E3, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6 ) ]
[8.198592, 8019.84192, 8001984.0192, 8000198400.192]
>>> nCPUs = 16; k = 2.1; [ ( 8 * N * ( N * N + nCPUs * (3+N*(k+1)))/1E9 ) for N in ( 1E3, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6 ) ]
[8.397184, 8039.68384, 8003968.0384, 8000396800.384]
 8[GB]     |...[GB]    |  |...[GB]   |  |  |...[GB]
           8   [TB]    |...   [TB]   |  |...   [TB]
                       8      [PB]   |...      [PB]
                                     8         [EB]
```

---

### EPILOGUE :

So a simple SLOC, using an as easy syntax as that of the `joblib.Parallel()(delayed()())` can immediately devastate the whole so far performed efforts of the computing graph in one, unsalvageable manner if a proper design effort was not spent on at least a raw data-processing quantitative estimate.

Comment: Thanks @user3666197. Memory is definitely an issue for my algorithm but I have some how resolved this by separating the data into chucks and parallezing the chucks rather than parallezing each data point.