# When specifying say n_jobs=-1 in scikit-learn's packages, do we need to first import joblib.Parallel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

When using scikit-learn's packages which has the option to choose a value for `n_jobs` for parallel processing, do we need to first import `joblib.Parallel` or will the scikit-learn package work with parallel processing without needing to first import `joblib.Parallel`.

Some of scikit-learn packages which has parallel processing are:

- sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression
- xgboost.XGBRegressor
- xgboost.XGBClassifier

etc.

Comment: No, you don't have to import `joblib`

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Looking at the source code of the various scikit-learn packages which has the option for parallel processing, how does the packages locate `joblib` if we didn't import `joblib` in the first place? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"... **do we need** to first import `joblib.Parallel` **or** will the scikit-learn package work with parallel processing without needing to first import `joblib.Parallel`." ?*

The **B** is correct : scikit-learn will work, as it was properly designed and implemented, so as to manage its own internal needs to import whatever package it knowingly depends on. This is a professional software standard to take due care of its own internal dependencies, isn't it?

---

### BONUS PART for those [*indeed interested*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60585100) in [*understanding WHY*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60695030) :

> Those who indeed want to see the trick - check the way of inheritance done on one of the packages source-level, obvious from the files reported below :

```
(base) Tue Mar 17 12:00:34 a64FX:~$ grep -R "joblib.Parallel" /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py:        parallel : joblib.Parallel (optional)
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py:            Pre-initialized instance of joblib.Parallel.
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py:        parallel : joblib.Parallel
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py:            Pre-initialized instance of joblib.Parallel
Binary file /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__pycache__/online_lda.cpython-35.pyc matches
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:                print("Using %s as joblib.Parallel backend instead of %s "
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:    """Callback used by joblib.Parallel's multiprocessing backend.
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_dask.py:        joblib.Parallel will never access those results
            /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_dask.py:        # See 'joblib.Parallel.__call__' and 'joblib.Parallel.retrieve' for how
Binary file /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__pycache__/parallel.cpython-35.pyc matches
Binary file /home/r2d2/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py35h4989274_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__pycache__/_dask.cpython-35.pyc matches
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help here @user3666197. The key take-out here is scikit-learn packages have built-in inheritance from scikit-learn's baseestimator